# MySQL joining tables with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, web

I've been scratching my head at this problem all day and I simple just can't work it out. This is the first time I've attempted to try and use SQL Joining, while we do kinda get taught the basics I'm more into pushing a little more into the advanced stuff.

Basically I'm making my own forum, and I have two tables. f_topics (The threads) and f_groups (The forums, or categories). There is a relationship between topicBase in f_topics and groupID in f_groups, this shows which group each topic belongs to. Each topic has a unique ID called topicID and same for the groups, called groupID.

Basically, I'm trying to get all these columns into a single SELECT statement - The title of the topic, the date the topic was posted, the ID of the group the topic belongs in, and the name of that group. This is what I was trying to use, but the group always comes back as 1, even if the topic is in groupID 2:

```
$query=mysqli_query($link, "

SELECT `topicName`, `topicDate`, `groupName`, `groupID`
FROM `f_topics`
NATURAL JOIN `f_groups`
WHERE `f_topics`.`topicID`='$tid';


") or die("Failed to get topic detail E: ".mysqli_error());
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
```

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense, and if my entire logic is completely wrong, if so could you suggest an alternate method?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join tables, you need to map the foreign keys. Assuming your groups table has an `groupID` field, this is how you'd join them:

```
SELECT `topicName`, `topicDate`, `groupName`, `groupID`
FROM `f_topics`
LEFT JOIN `f_groups`
ON `f_topics`.`groupID` = `f_groups`.`groupID`
WHERE`f_topics`.`topicID`='$tid';
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ``... FROM `f_groups` LEFT JOIN `f_topics` ...`` instead?

Comment: I don't believe so, based on the requirement from the question.

Comment: I gather from the question that a topic belongs to a group, not the other way round. By suggesting your left join, you seem to be assuming that a topic may belong either to a non-existent group or to no group at all. Is that so?

Comment: If they're all assigned to a group, it wouldn't matter and the query would work, yes?

Comment: Yes, it would work, but why not use an *inner* join then? I mean, at first glance, a left join does suggest (it would for me) that non-matches are possible/expected, and so this may be a little confusing from the maintenance point of view. (And I *was* actually confused at the beginning with regard to your intentions.) Performance-wise, maybe the optimiser will be able to figure out that the left join in this particular case is equivalent to an inner join, but if it won't, the resulting query plan might turn out less efficient than that the optimiser would have produced for the inner join.

Comment: Anyway, I can't say much about performance and query plans, that's an area I'm still learning. For me, this was primarily a maintainability issue and, since the confusion is now sorted, I've got nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I gather there is a column in f_topics named "topicBase" which references the groupID column from the f_groups table.

Based on that assumption, you can perform either an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN. INNER requires there be an entry in both tables while LEFT requires there only be data in f_topics.

```
SELECT
    f_topics.topicName,
    f_topics.topicDate
    f_groups.groupName
    f_groups.groupID
FROM
    f_topics
INNER JOIN
    f_groups
    ON
    f_topics.topicBase = f_groups.groupID
WHERE
    f_topics.topicID = '$tid'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you avoid `NATURAL JOIN`.

Primarily because a working query can be broken by the addition of a new column in a referenced table, which matches a column name in the other referenced table.

Secondly, for any reader (reviewer) of the SQL, which columns are being matched to which columns is not clear, without a careful review of both tables.  (And, if someone has added a column that has broken the query, it makes it even more difficult to figure out what the JOIN criteria used to be, before the column was added.

---

Instead, I recommend you specify the column names in a predicate in the ON clause.

It's also good practice to qualify all column references by table name, or preferably, a shorter table alias.

For simpler statements, I agree that this may look like unnecessary overhead. But once statements become more complicated, this pattern VASTLY improves the readability of the statement.

Absent the definitions of the two tables, I'm going to have to make assumptions, and I "guess" that there is a `groupID` column in both of those tables, and that is the only column that is named the same. But you specify that its the `topicBase` column in `f_topics` that matches `groupID` in `f_groups`. (And the NATURAL JOIN won't get you that.)

I think the resultset you want will be returned by this query:

```
SELECT t.`topicName`
     , t.`topicDate`
     , g.`groupName`
     , g.`groupID`
  FROM `f_topics` t
  JOIN `f_groups` g
    ON g.`groupID` = t.`topicBase`
 WHERE t.`topicID`='$tid';
```

If its possible for the `topicBase` column to be NULL or to contain a value that does not match a f_groups.GroupID value, and you want that topic returned, with the columns from f_group returned as NULL (when there is no match), you can get that with an outer join.

To get that behavior, in the query above, add the `LEFT` keyword immediately before the `JOIN` keyword.